# how to fetch data from a database?

Tags: php

let's say that I have a database of coaches and players , there is coaches table1 like this :

> id
>   name
>   icon

and the players table2 is like this :

> id
>   name
>   age
>   id_coach

how to get all players of every coach , with name and ages of players(table2) and name and icons of every coach from table1 ?

I have this sql request but its displaying only names and names of players

```
       SELECT a.name AS coachName, a.icon , b.name , b.age 
        FROM table1 a JOIN
             table2 b
         ON b.id_coach = a.id order by a.id;


                           $output = array();
                            $output2 = '';
                            foreach($this->CoachPlayers as $key => $value){
                                $coachName = $value['coachName'];
                                $coachImage = $value['icon'];
                                $age = $value['age'];
                                if (!array_key_exists($coachName, $output)) {
                                    $output[$coachName] = array();
                                }   
                                $output[$coachName][] = $value['name'];
                                $output[$coachName]['image'] = $value['icon'];
                            }

                            foreach($output as $data => $values) {

                                echo  "<h1>".$data."</h1>";
                                echo '<div style="text-align:center;"><img src="'.URL."public/images/coaches/".$coachImage.'"  /></div>';

                                foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                                    '<p>'.$value.' </p>';
                                    '<p>'.$age.' </p>';

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Does the query work as expected when executed on DB?

Comment: no errors , but its displaying only name of coach and name of players , no icon of coach and no age of player

Comment: I see there is an entity CoachPlayers, how are you populating this? Please show us that code too

Comment: $CoachPlayers is where we storing data that its coming from sql request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code, it should work.

```
    $output = array();
$output2 = '';
foreach($this->CoachPlayers as $key => $value){
    $coachName = $value['coachName'];
    $coachImage = $value['icon'];
    if (!array_key_exists($coachName, $output)) {
        $output[$coachName] = array();
    }
    $player = array();
    $player['name'] = $value['name'];
    $player['age'] = $value['age'];
    $output[$coachName][] = $player;
    $output[$coachName]['image'] = $value['icon'];
}

foreach($output as $data => $values) {
    $coachImage = $values['image'];
    echo  "<h1>".$data."</h1>";
    echo '<div style="text-align:center;"><img src="'.URL."public/images/coaches/".$coachImage.'"/></div>';

    if(is_array($values)) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $player) {
            echo '<p>'.$player['name'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$player['age'].'</p>';
        }
    }
}
```